# does that question show a bug in asker identity?

Tags: support

In the [unanswered list with the most vote](https://unix.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=votes) the top question :
[Completing avfs fake directories in zsh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/43883/53092)

appears asked by [Shawn J. Goff](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/2180/shawn-j-goff)

[image: extract of the top voted unanswered question with the above mentioned question]
Then when you open the question there's no answer no comment no edit and it appears asked by [Gilles](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/885/gilles)
[image: the core of the question that shows what describe before.]

As both user are still active could it result from a bug or an edition by a moderator ?
And who's the OP ?

---

#### edit:

The same happen with all the quesitons of the list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In the [unanswered list with the most vote](https://unix.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=votes) the top question :
>   [Completing avfs fake directories in zsh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/43883/53092)
>
> appears asked by [Shawn J. Goff](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/2180/shawn-j-goff)

It doesn't, actually:

[image: modified Feb 14 at 14:24]

It means Shawn J. Goff was the last person to have activity in the thread. In this case, he edited the answer that was there, but that answer was deleted the next day.